# how to pass element tree to other function TypeError: 'ElementTree' object is not iterable - - -

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to return the entire XML chunk to the controller in order to make them downloaded as an XML file.

```
  from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET  
    @api.model
    def _xml_download(self): 
        root = ET.Element("Test A")
        doc = ET.Element("Test B")
        root.append(doc)
        return ET.ElementTree(root)
```

And here is my controller:

```
class TestXMl(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/xml/download/report', type='http', auth="user")
    @serialize_exception
    def sale_xml_download(self, model, id, filename=None, **kw):
        filename = 'Test%s.xml'%('Test')
        records= http.request.env['sale.order'].search([('some_attribute', '=', True)])
        if records:
            xml_record = http.request.env['sale.order']._xml_download()
        else:
            xml_record = 'Test'
        filename = 'Test%s.xml'%('Test')

        headers = [
                ('Content-Type', 'application/xml'),
                ('Content-Disposition', content_disposition(filename)),
                ('charset', 'utf-8'),
            ]
        return request.make_response(
                    xml_record, headers=headers, cookies=None)
```

But I xml_record is not getting the element tree. It is saying `TypeError: 'ElementTree' object is not iterable - - -` In this case how we suppose to pass the elementTree. Looking for useful response, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`_xml_download` method returns an `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` object which is not iterable.

You can find in the documentation of the method [request.make_response](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/http.py#L849):

```
param basestring data: response body
```

Try to return `ET.tostring(root)`

*Note that passing data as a list of strings should work*